# Save screen brightness adjustment?

Tags: 14.04, brightness, thinkpad

My laptop is Thinkpad T400 and I am running 14.04. Every time I decrease the brightness of my screen, it will be back to 100% next time I reboot. How can I save the adjustment and apply it once for all? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with 14.04 and now with 14.10 but on a different computer (Dell Inspiron). I hope someone has a fix for this!

Comment: I didn't have the problem with 12.04.

Comment: The solution at webupd8 worked for me too. @DK-Bose: Why don't you post an answer copying those steps here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Intel 4500MHD - you need to set a value in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to whatever is comfortable. A value is simply written here. First, find out what the max value is by running

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
```

In my case it is 5273. After you reduce the brightness to something comfortable, check the value in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` by running

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

In my case it was 2040. To set this value at boot time just type

`sudo echo "echo "2040 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness" >> /etc/rc.local"` so that this value is set at boot up.

This is what I did on my Lenovo G510 using the Intel 4500 graphics. If you are running the AMD M82XT Graphics I'm afraid I can't help you.